# What is paint32 in pyaudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

i'm using pyaudio with a microphone.
I've got a problem with the meaning of :

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt32.
```

I've been searching for a while but found nothing about it.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068268/difference-between-paint32-paint16-paint24-pafloat32-etc answer it? including the link to the Google book in the comment on the answer. It's an Int32 (a 32-bit integer) and it's a PyAudio (pa) version of it, apparently so you can work with audio using 32bit integer values even when they aren't natively supported by the lower levels.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation found [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#overview), `pyaudio.paInt32` is one of many types of PortAudio Sample Format.

When you are using a software library like PyAudio, I always recommend looking for official documentation, which can be done by going on the official repository page and looking for links to the documentation. For example, here is the path I took to find the answer:

1. Google "PyAudio"
2. Visit the PyPi repository: https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/
3. Go to the homepage of the library: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/
4. Go the linked official documentation: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/
5. Search (Ctrl+f) for `paInt32` and found http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/